# openldap synchronize with local users and groups

Tags: linux, openldap

I have a server running openldap 2.4.31 in which I store my user and group posix accounts. How can I automatically copy the user and group accounts on the first login so that if the machine disconnects from the ldap server the user can still login? Also, would it be possible to automatically update the password and group membership for the local account if it is updated on the ldap server provided they are connected again?

The openldap server is running on ubuntu 14.04 and the other machines are running ubuntu 14.04, CentOS 7 and Arch linux.

What would be the common way to solve this in a company network running only linux machines? With windows machines this seems to be solved using active directory and maybe some policies but in a company with centralized login servers and laptops with either linux only or mixed OS I supposed this is done with ldap or radius or both.

Comment: It sounds to me like it might be an XY problem, and that an LDAP replication slave might be a cleaner solution.

Comment: @JeffSchaller would that require me to have an ldap database on every client that needs this feature?

Comment: ...and to configure replication and the clients to include its own replica as a server.

Comment: @JeffSchaller seems like it must exist a less complex solution that wouldn't require ldap replication but maybe not as clean.

Comment: I'm not aware of one; you have competing goals of local access versus centralized management. My two cents - focus on why your server(s) are disconnecting from LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replicate your data to every machine if I understood you right. For that you'll need to use Syncrepl, please read the documentation in order to implement it: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html#Syncrepl

I hope that this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can [setup PAM to cache data from ldap](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html)